# Add Scrollbar in Tkinter, to show Image outside the Frame

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scroll, scrollbar

My objective is to add a vertical scroll bar to a frame which has several labels in it. The scroll bar should automatically enabled as soon as the labels inside the frame exceed the height of the frame.
I would like to display a product description page in Tkinter. It contains a scrollBar to scroll through the bottom, to view the all listed product.
I had created two rows on which i want to scroll through downward.

but after placing it , i am only able to see the scrollbar widget without the scroll function, and the scroll wheel is not available.

I had used an image of resolution - (310 X 480)pixels

So, can anyone suggest me what was i doing wrong. and help me to properly enable scroll through it.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")
title = Label(root, text="Product Catalogue", font=("Lucida Handwriting", 20), bg='lightblue', bd=10, relief=GROOVE).pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
manage_Frame = Frame(root, bd=7, relief=RIDGE, bg="grey")
manage_Frame.place(x=13, y=70, width=1320, height=580)
manage_Frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
manage_Frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
xscrollbar = Scrollbar(manage_Frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
xscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
yscrollbar = Scrollbar(manage_Frame)
yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
canvas = Canvas(manage_Frame, bd=0, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("F:\\img.jpg"))
lbl1 = Label(canvas, image=img1, padx=20, pady=20)
lbl1.place(x=0, y=0) 
lbl_size1 = Label(canvas, text="Size:", bg="pink").place(x=10,y=400) 
size1 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, font=("Century Gothic", 10), state='readonly', width=4)
size1["value"] = ("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL")
size1.place(x=40, y=400) 
lbl_qty1 = Label(canvas, text="Qty:", bg="pink").place(x=12,y=400) 
qty1 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, font=("Century Gothic", 10), state='readonly', width=4)
qty1["value"] = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
qty1.place(x=150, y=400) 
price1 = Label(canvas, text="Rs 2000", font=("Sitka Heading", 10)).place(x=10, y=20)

img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("F:\\img.jpg"))
lbl2 = Label(canvas, image=img2, padx=20, pady=20)
lbl2.place(x=310, y=0, ) 
lbl_size2 = Label(canvas, text="Size:", bg="pink").place(x=372, y=400)  
size2 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, font=("Century Gothic", 10), state='readonly', width=4)
size2["value"] = ("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL")
size2.place(x=402, y=400)
lbl_qty2 = Label(canvas, text="Qty:", bg="pink").place(x=467, y=400)  
qty2 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, font=("Century Gothic", 10), state='readonly', width=4)
qty2["value"] = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
qty2.place(x=497, y=400)  
price2 = Label(canvas, text="Rs 1800", font=("Sitka Heading", 10)).place(x=372, y=20)

img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("F:\\img.jpg"))
lbl3 = Label(canvas, image=img3, padx=20, pady=20)
lbl3.place(x=620, y=0, )  
lbl_size3 = Label(canvas, text="Size:", bg="pink").place(x=670, y=400) 
size3 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, font=("Century Gothic", 10), state='readonly', width=4)
size3["value"] = ("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL")
size3.place(x=700, y=400) 
lbl_qty3 = Label(canvas, text="Qty:", bg="pink").place(x=765, y=400) 
qty3 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, font=("Century Gothic", 10), state='readonly', width=4)
qty3["value"] = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
qty3.place(x=795, y=400)  
price3 = Label(canvas, text="Rs 3000", font=("Sitka Heading", 10)).place(x=670, y=20)

img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("F:\\img.jpg"))
lbl4 = Label(canvas, image=img4, padx=20, pady=20)
lbl4.place(x=930, y=0, ) 
lbl_size4 = Label(canvas, text="Size:", bg="pink").place(x=980, y=400)
size4 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, font=("Century Gothic", 10), state='readonly', width=4)
size4["value"] = ("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL")
size4.place(x=1010, y=400) 
lbl_qty4 = Label(canvas, text="Qty:", bg="pink").place(x=1075, y=400) 
qty4 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, font=("Century Gothic", 10), state='readonly', width=4)
qty4["value"] = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
qty4.place(x=1105, y=400)  
price4 = Label(canvas, text="Rs 1500", font=("Sitka Heading", 10)).place(x=980, y=20)

img5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("F:\\img.jpg"))
lbl5 = Label(canvas, image=img5, padx=20, pady=20)
lbl5.place(x=0, y=480, )  
lbl_size5 = Label(canvas, text="Size :", bg="pink").place(x=10,y=880) 
size5 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, font=("Century Gothic", 10), state='readonly', width=4)
size5["value"] = ("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL")
size5.place(x=40, y=880)  
lbl_qty5 = Label(canvas, text="Qty : ", bg="pink").place(x=120,y=880)
qty5 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, font=("Century Gothic", 10), state='readonly', width=4)
qty5["value"] = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
qty5.place(x=150, y=880) 
price5 = Label(canvas, text="Rs 2000", font=("Sitka Heading", 10)).place(x=10, y=500)

img6 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("F:\\img.jpg"))
lbl6 = Label(canvas, image=img6, padx=20, pady=20)
lbl6.place(x=310, y=480, )
lbl_size6 = Label(canvas, text="Size :", bg="pink").place(x=372, y=880) 
size6 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, font=("Century Gothic", 10), state='readonly', width=4)
size6["value"] = ("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL")
size6.place(x=402, y=880)  
lbl_qty6 = Label(canvas, text="Qty : ", bg="pink").place(x=467, y=880) 
qty6 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, font=("Century Gothic", 10), state='readonly', width=4)
qty6["value"] = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
qty6.place(x=497, y=880)
price6 = Label(canvas, text="Rs 2000", font=("Sitka Heading", 10)).place(x=372, y=500)

img7 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("F:\\img.jpg"))
lbl7 = Label(canvas, image=img7, padx=20, pady=20)
lbl7.place(x=620, y=480, ) 
lbl_size7 = Label(canvas, text="Size :", bg="pink").place(x=670, y=880) 
size7 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, font=("Century Gothic", 10), state='readonly', width=4)
size7["value"] = ("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL")
size7.place(x=700, y=880) 
lbl_qty7 = Label(canvas, text="Qty : ", bg="pink").place(x=765, y=880) 
qty7 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, font=("Century Gothic", 10), state='readonly', width=4)
qty7["value"] = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
qty7.place(x=795, y=880) 
price7 = Label(canvas, text="Rs 2000", font=("Sitka Heading", 10)).place(x=670, y=500)

img8 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("F:\\img.jpg"))
lbl8 = Label(canvas, image=img8, padx=20, pady=20)
lbl8.place(x=930, y=480, ) 
lbl_size8 = Label(canvas, text="Size :", bg="pink").place(x=980, y=880) 
size8 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, font=("Century Gothic", 10), state='readonly', width=4)
size8["value"] = ("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL")
size8.place(x=1010, y=880) 
lbl_qty8 = Label(canvas, text="Qty : ", bg="pink").place(x=1075,y=880)  
qty8 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, font=("Century Gothic", 10), state='readonly', width=4)
qty8["value"] = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
qty8.place(x=1105, y=880)  
price1 = Label(canvas, text="Rs 2000", font=("Sitka Heading", 10)).place(x=950, y=500)

canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))

xscrollbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
yscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've told us what you want, but haven't explained what's preventing you from doing that. What sort of  help do you need? What is the code doing, and how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: I was not able to properly apply the scroll bar to scroll through the content outside the frame, Please guide.

Comment: You are putting the labels in a canvas, not in a frame.  Also `canvas.bbox(ALL)` will not give what you expect because you use `place()` to lay out the labels, not using `canvas.create_text()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't scroll items added to a canvas with `place`. You must use `create_window` in order to add the widgets to a scrollable canvas.